# Moving a Folder with Content from SSD (C:\) to HDD (D:\) Windows 8.1

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1, ssd

I was wondering if there are any issues I should be aware of when moving a folder (in my case it is Final Fantasy XIV: A Realm Reborn) from my "Program Files" on my C:\ (SSD) to my HDD (D:) on my laptop. Can I just simply drag and drop the folder over from C:\Program Files to D:\Program Files?

If there is some other way I should go about doing this, please let me know. Thank you. I'd like to avoid downloading the game over again because I do have data limits, and if I can avoid the large download process it would be great.

Comment: Just dragging it from C: to D: will not work. You could either:
1) Deinstall and then during reinstallation select D:
2) Or make a softlink from C:\Program files\ff8 to D:\ff8.  (copy, move the old folder on C: make softlink or junction).

Comment: Is there a reason it may not work? Is it because something like "Shortcuts to FF XIV" will not be assigned properly, or is it because something else like the game's assets and files may look at the wrong path and therefore also have issues? Just trying to see what could be the issue, but thanks for the comment. I'll look into those two.

Comment: It should work. As far as a program is concerned the path to the files has not changed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to save space on SSD, what you need to do is moving the folder to D then make a link on C. Otherwise, a simple move might make the game fail to start. Run command line below as Administrator from cmd. Replace "Final Fantasy XIV" with the actual directory name.

```
mklink /d "c:\program files\Final Fantasy XIV"  "d:\program files\Final Fantasy XIV"
```

Comment: Thank you. One question, is there any chance, or do you maybe know from experience, if the game itself can suffer any issues as opposed to just reinstalling it again and removing the game from its current directory?

Comment: reinstall to new location would be safest, can't say for sure for the game but from my experience, softlink works for most, if not all apps even windows itself.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I will probably end up biting the bullet for this game, just in case. I will try with some smaller games though, see how that works, but for this I feel learning what I have, maybe the best bet is to just go forward with a full reinstall, just in case.